# Efficient way to keep only highest ranked observation for each group

Tags: sas

I want to keep only the row with the highest rank1 for each team. If there is a tie, I want the row with the higher rank2. And then the higher rank3.

For example,

```
data test;
input name $ team $ rank1 rank2 rank3 country $
datalines;
Bob A 5 6 5 US   
Joe A 8 2 6 UK
Dav B 9 7 2 GER
Jim B 9 4 4 FRA
Bob C 3 4 1 FRA
Dan D 5 2 7 GER
Ike D 5 2 7 US
Jay D 5 2 8 UK
run;
```

I want:

```
Joe A 8 2 6 UK
Dav B 9 7 2 GER
Bob C 3 4 1 FRA
Jay D 5 2 8 UK
```

What is the most efficient way to do this? The dataset I'm working with is pretty big and is not sorted. I tried the below code but the sorts take forever to run. And the second sort sorts already sorted data. What if most teams only appear once in the dataset? Is it faster to split into duplicates and non-duplicates, sort only the duplicates and then append?

```
proc sort data=test;
by team descending rank1 descending rank2 descending rank3;
run;

proc sort data=test nodupkey;
by team;
run;
```

Comment: Please add an examples of ties in your sample data and the expected output for that tied record. Not quite understanding how you want it handled. Do you have to keep this data structure? It's much easier with a long data set instead of wide data set.

Comment: If there are ties for all three ranks, it can pick any of the tied rows. I would prefer to keep the data structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with PROC SUMMARY.  Not sure about performance compared to what you are already doing.

```
proc summary data=test nway;
   class team;
   output out=ranked(drop=_:) idgroup(max(rank:) out(name rank: country)=);
   run;
```

[image]